# Is there a rewrite tactic in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

For example in Coq there is `rewrite` and we can also put arrows `<-:

```
Inductive bool: Set :=
  | true
  | false.

Lemma equality_of_functions_commutes:
  forall (f: bool->bool) x y,
    (f x) = (f y) -> (f y) = (f x).
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

source: https://pjreddie.com/coq-tactics/#rewrite

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that it is as strong as the Coq version, but

- [subst, described in 5.8.1 of the old tutorial](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/tutorial.pdf) and
- [rewrite, shown in the examples](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-ex/Rewrite_Examples.html)

rewrite theorems. However, you cannot easily rewrite assumptions in apply-style.

Comment: what about reflexivity?

Comment: The closest thing to reflexivity is probably `apply (simp (no_asm))`, but it is very unnatural to do use that instead of `apply simp`.

Comment: This is merely a side remark: it seems that for Pinocchio's particular application it may be best to use `apply(rule refl)` or simply `..` instead of `simp (no_ams)` or `simp`, given that the two terms obtained as a result of the application of rewriting will be entirely identical. Of course, overall, it seems that `simp (no_asm)` is, indeed, as close as one can get to Coq's `reflexivity`.